# Comment qualifier le « (offset) cube (displaced a metre from the main vertical axis ) » d'un immeuble ?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, formulation-idiomatique, lexique

Dans cette image, on peut voir l'architecture d'un immeuble fait de « cubes superposés ». Or, la position de celui du dessus diffère de celle des autres :

> Visually, the **offset** cube on the top floor of the building appears
> much bigger than the others, however, it is of the same size. The
> organisation of the building is similar to the Ken organisational
> framework, a traditional Japanese method which governs the structure
> and the additive sequence, from space to space. The 4×4 cube, which is
> **displaced a metre from the main vertical axis** on the top floor,
> together with the vast transparent windows, lend a higher level of
> importance to the design. The cube produces a seemingly larger visual
> scale, in spite of it being the same as the other cubes which form the
> tower: 4×4. ([Wikiarquitectura](https://en.wikiarquitectura.com/building/4x4-house/), *4x4 House*, Tadao Ando, je souligne)

[image]

La qualification de « offset cube » ne s'appuie sur aucun autre référent dans la phrase (il est « offset » tout court), tandis que dans la deuxième phrase on parle de l'étage supérieur dont on dit du « cube » qu'il est « displaced a metre from the main vertical axis ». Je cherche à employer des termes ou locutions servant les mêmes fonctions dans des phrases similaires (donc seuls ou en relation avec un autre concept ou point de référence) afin de décrire la partie supérieure de cet immeuble. J'ai trouvé *(faire) [ressaut](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ressaut)* mais je ne sais pas vraiment comment l'employer (préposition, formulation etc.) ni si c'est usuel en architecture ou pertinent ici.

Comment parle-t-on du « cube » de cet immeuble dans une phrase complète avec « faire ressaut » ou autrement, comme on le fait dans le citation, en fonction de ces critères ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On peut traduire *offset* par ***[décalage](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9calage)*** dans de nombreux contextes, y compris celui-ci. Le dernier étage est *en décalage* par rapport au reste du bâtiment. Comme *offset*, ce terme qualifie l'étage dans son ensemble, pas seulement le fait que la façade est plus avancée. Il s'agit d'un décalage (*offset*) parce que le mur du fond est aussi décalé que le mur avant.

Le fait que le l'avant soit décalé par rapport au reste constitue une *[saillie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saillie_(architecture))*, et on peut dire que le dernier étage est *en saillie*. Une *saillie* est un terme générique qui peut désigner n'importe quoi qui dépasse.

L'avant est au dessus d'un espace extérieur, donc c'est un *[surplomb](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/surplomb), et on peut dire que le dernier étage est *en surplomb*. Les termes *saillie* et *surplomb* sont presque synonymes, mais pas complètement. Notamment, un pont est un surplomb mais pas une saillie. Je pense qu'en architecture, on ne parlerait pas de surplomb pour une très petite saillie sur laquelle on ne peut pas marcher (et de même en escalade, si la roche dépasse de quelques centimètres, c'est une saillie qui forme un appui, et non un surplomb qui est un obstacle).

Je cite plusieurs termes spécialisés d'architecture, dont certains ont été suggérés dans cette discussion, qui ne conviennent pas car ils ont un sens précis qui n'est pas le bon (et qui ne sont pas compréhensibles du grand public) :

- Je ne suis pas sûr pour *ressaut*. En général, et en géologie en particulier, un ressaut est une différence de hauteur, pas une différence de plan vertical. Cela apparaît clairement dans les définitions de [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ressaut/68711) et [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/ressaut) en référence à un paysage, mais les définitions architecturales sont plus vagues. En revanche *dictionnaire professionel du [BTP](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A2timents_et_travaux_publics)* d'[Eyrolles](https://www.editions-eyrolles.com/Dico-BTP/definition.html?id=7943) limite le terme à un « décrochement vertical ou changement de niveau brusque ». Donc *ressaut* n'est pas un bon terme spécialisé, mais il se peut qu'il soit utilisé de façon plus large par des non-spécialistes (cela dit, la question se poserait de quels non-spécialistes, puisque ce n'est pas un terme courant et que les géologues et montagnards ne parleraient pas de *ressaut* pour un surplomb).
- La partie qui dépasse est peut-être un *[oriel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriel)* (puisque c'est entièrement une baie vitrée), mais en général un oriel est une partie de bâtiment qui dépasse, alors qu'ici c'est l'étage entier qui dépasse.
- S'il y avait plusieurs étages dont chacun dépasse un peu plus que l'étage au dessous, on parlerait d'*[encorbellement](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encorbellement)*. Mais le principe de l'encorbellement est le dépassement graduel, donc le terme ne convient pas ici.
- Il ne s'agit pas d'un *[redan ou redent](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redent)* qui est une avancée d'un mur entier et pas d'un étage seul.

Comment: Que dirais-tu de « décentré » ?

Answer (score -1):

On peut parler de ce cube comme étant *en encorbellement par rapport* au niveau inférieur, ou par rapport au cube inférieur, ou encore, de façon peut-être plus courante, comme étant *en ressaut par rapport au* niveau inférieur.

Au lieu de « par rapport à » On peut aussi utiliser l'expression « *en surplomb sur* » ou « *en surplomb de* » ; dans ce cas, un complément de la préposition doit être différent (façade, [nu](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nu_(architecture)) du mur du niveau inférieur).

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/encorbellement)) **encorbellement** ARCHIT. Construction formant saillie sur le plan vertical d'un mur et soutenue en porte à faux par des corbeaux ou des consoles.
> •  Il allait hériter des couronnes murales, des fossés, des créneaux, des encorbellements (Péguy, Ève,1913, p. 862).
> • Des maisons noires et rabougries qui portent leur étage sur un encorbellement à dessous sculpté (T'Serstevens, Itinér. esp.,1963, p. 228).
> **En encorbellement** En saillie du plan vertical d'un mur. Bâtir en encorbellement;
> • plate-forme, terrasse en encorbellement.
> • D'ordinaire, les échauguettes avancent en encorbellement hors du rempart, afin de permettre aux sentinelles d'en voir le pied (Mérimée, Ét. arts Moy. Âge,1870, p. 248)
> •
> Ils passèrent par une galerie en encorbellement sur la cour, et entrèrent dans une grande salle éclairée par une girandole placée sur une torchère de bois doré. Borel, Champavert,Dina, la belle juive, 1833, p. 133.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ressaut)) **ressaut**  a) ARCHIT. Saillie en dehors d'une ligne ou d'une surface

([Thorikos - Volumes 1 à 3 Comité des fouilles belges en Grèce](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Thorikos/v60VAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22en+ressaut+par+rapport%22&dq=%22en+ressaut+par+rapport%22&printsec=frontcover)) Le parement repose sur une assise de pierres plates qui lui servent de fondation et qui se trouvent légèrement en ressaut par rapport aux façades du monument .

([La peinture murale romane dans les Pays de la Loire](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_peinture_murale_romane_dans_les_Pays/0wbrAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22en+ressaut+par+rapport%22&dq=%22en+ressaut+par+rapport%22&printsec=frontcover)) L'amande du ventre est nettement en ressaut par rapport au corps, de même les plis en V et posés de biais sur la cuisse droite matérialisent deux moments différents en un seul lieu et enfin , la plage unie sur le devant du torse ... (*Il ne s'agit pas d'architecture, dans cet exemple.*)

« Encorbellement » semble être le terme préféré en architecture, d'après le TLFi dont l'entrée présente un terme spécifiquement dédié à l'architecture et d'après la fréquence d'usage dans une expression qui semble  plus propre à l'architecture à cause de la plus grande spécificité que les descriptions nécessitent..

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Wikipédia, Thiers, rue de la Coutellerie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encorbellement#/media/Fichier:Rue_de_la_coutellerie.jpg)

> [**Encorbellement**, Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encorbellement)) En maçonnerie, « encorbellement » et « assise en encorbellement » désignent toute saillie qui porte à faux au nu d'un mur, formée par une ou plusieurs pierres posées l'une sur l'autre, et plus saillantes les unes que les autres. Le principe de l'encorbellement permet de construire des voûtes ou des arcs dits en encorbellement, plus facilement que l'arc en plein cintre qui fait appel à des cintres en bois.
>
> De manière plus large, l'encorbellement, système de construction de pierre ou de bois, permet de porter une charge en surplomb sur le nu d'un mur, d'une pile, d'un contrefort. On dit construction en encorbellement pour désigner la partie d'une bâtisse posée sur un encorbellement.

Comment: « Encorbellement » ne traduit pas « offset » parce qu'il ne s'applique qu'à la façade, pas à l'étage entier. De plus, un encorbellement est en principe graduel : je ne pense pas qu'on parlerait d'un encorbellement s'il n'y a que deux plans verticaux.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Plusieurs étages et donc plusieurs plans verticaux ne sont pas nécessaires pour parler d'encorbellement ; on parle de tourelles en encorbellement (https://www.meubliz.com/definition/encorbellement/), et il ne s'agit même pas de tourelles entières. Quant aux cubes, ils n'ont pas à être de la même forme, et il ne le sont pas dans l'illustration du PO.